# Proof of DMCA Violation?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, copyright, copyright-infringement

The following StackOverflow post was just hidden because of a supposed DMCA takedown request:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411535/solving-a-jigzaw-puzzle-with-python/69412120#69412120

I find that almost inconceivable.  I remember the post, and I remember the poster had numerous problems in his code.  If this truly was infringing a copyright, I would like to see the copyrighted source.  Are the DMCA takedown requests registered publicly anywhere?

Comment: I guess it does, but it's not very satisfying, is it?  I'd like to tag it with #I-dont-believe-you, but there's no avenue for doing that.

Comment: By the looks of it the problem is used by a company as part of its recruitment process. It seems unlikely that company wants anyone to make the question public as the point is to get each candidate to provide their own answer.

Comment: I'm very confused why/when we began redacting for DMCA notices. That makes it difficult to impossible for a user who disagrees with a DMCA to challenge it because the content is literally gone... That was never part of the process before.

Comment: @RobertLongson  You may be right, and if the candidate was asked to keep it confidential it would certainly be an ethics violation, but I don't see how it rises to a DMCA violation.  But I do appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @animuson With a DMCA takedown, you must *actually* take it down (i.e. stop serving that content). From a legal POV, and given SE's system, just a delete wouldn't be sufficient, as you're still serving the content, even though it's to a more limited set of people (those that can see deleted posts). IMO, redacting is *required* for compliance with the DMCA. I don't necessarily like it, but I don't see a way that it *wouldn't* be required.

Comment: @Makyen Our legal team had always agreed that deletion was a sufficient handling of a DMCA and that was all we did up until like 3-ish months ago when I stopped processing them. This is just quite a departure form our usual process we've always used for as long as I've worked here.

Comment: @animuson That's an…interesting position form your legal team (do they know "delete" isn't *really* deleting?). Obviously, go with what your legal team says. I'll add it to the list of their positions about which I'm…highly skeptical. The crux of it is that you must "remove, or disable access to, the material", which deleting *doesn't* do. OTOH, the last time I checked, SO arguably doesn't comply with other DMCA requirements in a way which permits SO/SE to take advantage of the liability shield, so, what's done to the post may not matter. It is interesting that what's being done has changed.

Comment: @Makyen Fair enough. Though arguably if our legal team's position on this changed, it would be far better to invest a little bit of dev time to finally add a DMCA lock, which could just make the post only visible to the author and staff, both of which should be able to still view it to either send a counter-claim or verify a received counter-claim. Redacting is a very inappropriate and destructive tool to be using here.

Comment: @animuson I quite agree, that is development work which really should be done and which would be *much* better than redacting. However, it looks like redaction is the only current option that actually does "remove, or disable access to, the material". Obviously, you could have a developer manipulate the database, but that would effectively be redaction anyway.

Comment: @animuson The reason I said SO arguably doesn't comply is that [17 U.S.C. § 512(c)(2)](//www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/512#c_2) requires that to qualify for the liability shield SE *must* have a "designated an agent to receive notifications of claimed infringement" and make available "including *on its website*…accessible to the public…the name, address, phone number, and electronic mail address of the agent." SE *[doesn't have that information about the designated agent on the website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387746/3773011)*, so doesn't qualify for the liability shield.